# How to split class B addresses into 3 subnets (1 should be larger than others)

Tags: ipv4, ip

I got this task recently and I'm not sure, how to work with masks in classful addressing. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: This sounds very much like homework (and severely out-of-date homework at that unless it's about archaeology) which is off-topic.

Comment: Actually, it's a question from a test, that I got in school and I couldn't figure out how to do that, so I'm just asking here to get the answer, so I can fix my grade.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are long obsolete (since 1993!), replaced by CIDR in [RFC 1518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1518) and [RFC 1519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1519).

What class B used to be back in the days is now known as /16, which you can subnet into four /18 subnets, two of which you can rejoin into a /17 subnet.